# rails 3 - js.erb template is not executed when response status is 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In case an object with a particular ID is not found anytime in the lifecycle of a request, I want to show a flash error (via JS if the request was ajax or via rendering error page if request was HTML). I also want to respond with a 404.

```
flash[:error] = "#{e.message} was not found."
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { render "errors/runtime_error", :status => 404 }
        format.js { render :template => "shared/_flash.js.erb", :status => 404 }
      end
      return
```

The problem is that with the above code, the _flash.js.erb is not being executed on the client if the request was AJAX. However, if i remove the `:status => 404`, then the _flash.js.erb is executed as expected.

Is this something to expect? If so, how I can get around it? If this should not be happening, what could be the issue?

Thanks.

Comment: did you ever get this working?